# Mounting caliper brakes without center hole

Tags: brakes

I recently purchased a used Bianchi Cross Concept. I'm trying to upgrade the entire groupset.

When coming to the rear brakes, I realized the bike frame has two holes (1 on each side) for mounting v-brakes. However, the new rear brakes are I got are caliper brakes which need to be mounted to a single hole in the center (see picture). It's a carbon frame so I can't drill anything.

I'm wondering if there are any methods to make this work, some sort of adapter perhaps?

[image]

Comment: Any adapter you get will flex too much to support the brakes.

Comment: What concerns do you have with the current cantilevers that make you think they need to be replaced.

Comment: Cross bikes tend to have cantilever brake arms for additional tyre clearance.  Caliper brakes can have QRs to facilitate wheel swaps, but cantis allow for much larger CS/gravel tyres.  I'd stay with the cantilever brakes.  Perhaps buy some new ones. or even consider V brakes if your levers are long-pull capable.

Comment: The bosses are not for mountain V-brakes. They are for caliper brakes. (Although, yes, you can convert your caliper brakes to something like mini-V brakes).

Answer (score 8):

You have a cyclocross bike. There is no reasonable way to add caliper brakes to that rear end, and probably the fork as well. Even if the frame was modified by bonding in a brake mount for a recessed nut, the reach of the brake that came with your group will be way too short, presuming it's a typical short reach road brake.

Low profile, smooth post cantis like you have are infamous for their finicky adjustment and tendency to squeal. If you want to modernize the bike, there are far nicer brakes you could get.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mount side-pull calipers as seen on rim brake road bikes.

Cantilever brakes are compatible with road brake levers but as Nathan points out they are difficult to set up right.

What you need are mini v-brakes. Those fit the mounting points and are compatible with road brake levers. Note that regular length v-brakes are *not* compatible with the levers.